# Having problem using comparison operator in pandas groupby function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

[image: The dataframe]

I'm stuck on following error on line 4: " ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). " , when I'm trying to get the max revenue among all shops in the month of September, 2014.

```
amt=[]
group=df.groupby(["shop_id"])
for i,j in group:
    if ((j["month"] == '9') & (j["year"] == '2014')):      #line 4 - error
        #print(i)
        #print(j)
        #print(x)
        
        x=np.sum(j['item_cnt_day']*j["item_price"])
        print("revenue: ",x)
        amt.append(x)
```